# SSLStream over Socks5 to IMAP. Cant write to Stream

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, imap, socks

I am trying to connect to a Socks5 Server, tell him to connect to a IMAP Server and get a Socket. I want to use the Socket to login in to the IMAP.
My Problem is, that after connecting to the IMAP using a SSL Stream i can only read from the Stream. After sending the login data i get no response from the IMAP Server.

Thats my Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {               
        Console.WriteLine("Working *");

        var socksClient = new TcpClient();
        socksClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1080);

        var bw = new BinaryWriter(socksClient.GetStream(), Encoding.Default, true);
        var br = new BinaryReader(socksClient.GetStream(), Encoding.Default, true);

        //Tell the Socks5 to Connect to the IMAP:

        //Get the IP of the IMAP
        var ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses("mx.freenet.de")[0];

        //Me: Hello

        bw.Write(new byte[] {0x05, 0x01, 0x00});

        //Server: Hello

        br.ReadBytes(2);

        //Me: Connect to the IMAP on port 993

        byte[] data =  {0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, getPortBytes(993)[0], getPortBytes(993)[1]};

        //Fill the IP in the DATA

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            data[i + 4] = ip.GetAddressBytes()[i];
        }

        bw.Write(data);

        //Server: Connection rdy

        br.ReadBytes(10);

        //Close our old Binary Writer/Reader

        br.Close();
        br.Dispose();
        bw.Close();
        bw.Dispose();

        //Handle SSL Stream

        var ssl = new SslStream(socksClient.GetStream(), false);

        //Auth as client
        ssl.AuthenticateAsClient("mx.freenet.de", null, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

        //Create new Binary Reader/Writer for the SSLStream
        var sslBr = new BinaryReader(ssl, Encoding.Default, true);
        var sslBw = new BinaryWriter(ssl, Encoding.Default, true);

        //Print the IMAP`s Hello
        string line = "";
        while (true)
        {
            char c = sslBr.ReadChar();
            line += c;
            if (c == '\n')
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                break;
            }
        }

        //Send login to IMAP

        sslBw.Write((". login fipso@freenet.de HIDDEN"));

        //Read response as bytes
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sslBr.ReadByte());
        }

        /*
            Server gives no response.
            Why ?
        */

    }
```

EDIT:
When running the code:

```
Working *
* OK IMAP ready.
```

Comment: You should be getting an exception on : socksClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1080);.  Net library gives always gives an exception when using Connect method on loopback IP 127.0.0.1.  So I don't know what you are actually getting. I would add an exception block to your code.

Comment: Rly? Does it ? That can not be true. I did this so often. .Net 4.5

Comment: You can listen, but not connect to 127.0.0.1.  I usually get a Refuse To Connect error.  But in my cases I'm using the same PC for both Listener and Client.  It may be that the error message occurs because I start the listener 1st.  In this case your server may also be using 127.0.0.1 and you can't have two sockets with same IP addresses.  Try from a cmd.exe following : >Netstat -a.See if any application is already listening to 127.0.0.1 : 1080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All IMAP commands must end in "\r\n".

It doesn't look like you've ended your command with any sort of new line.

Comment: Thanks. That was the Problem. Now i get a response by the Server.